# Is the exponential map ever not injective?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G\subseteq GL_n(\mathbb R)$ and let $\mathfrak g$ denote its Lie algebra.

Let $e: \mathfrak g \to G$ be the map $X \mapsto e^X$.

> Does there exist an example of $G$ and $\mathfrak g$ such that $e$ is
>   not injective?

Of course I think the answer is no, there is no such example because $e: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is injective.

> What about $G\subseteq GL_n(\mathbb C)$?

Since the map is the same I again think there should not exist such an example.

Comment: Over the complex numbers, have you considered the $n=1$ case?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, I hadn't, good point. If $n=1$ and $G=\mathbb C$ then also $\mathfrak g = \mathbb C$, right? And the complex exponential is not injective.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ${}$

Comment: Right. I have not thought much about the real case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a simple counterexample: The group $SO(2) \subset GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$; its Lie algebra is the space of skew-symmetric matricies, and its exponential map is given by
$$
   e : \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & t \\
-t & 0 \end{array} \right) \mapsto 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & \sin t \\
-\sin t & \cos t \end{array} \right) 
$$
which isn't injective.

Comment: That is a nice example!