# The condition for the exponential map of Lie group is surjective or injective

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

$G$ is a connected Lie group, $g$ is its Lie algebra.

1) What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the exponential map from $g$ to $G$ is surjective?

2) What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the exponential map from $g$ to $G$ is one-to-one?

Comment: This has been asked many times; check the links, e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130178/is-the-exponential-map-ever-not-injective?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089636/exponential-map-is-surjective-for-compact-connected-lie-group?rq=1), etc.

Comment: There isn't a nice criterion for either (1) or (2). You can read about it here: http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jlt/jlt07/DOKHOFPL.PDF.

Comment: @levap Yes, that is a very good link (I was just thinking of it). But nice or not nice, there are enough results.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, levap: I disagree with both of you about injectivity (I agree that surjectivity is more messy): for injectivity, a reasonable criterion can be formulated. See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective/1592257#1592257

Comment: @YCor: I never said anything to disagree about injectivity. I agree with you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde OK no problem :)