# For which Lie groups $G$ can one write $g$ as the exponential $\exp X$ of some $X \in {\frak g}$ for every element $g \in G$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading a book on matrix Lie algebras (Brian Hall's). Corollary 2.30. says that if  $G$ is a connected matrix Lie group, then every element $A$ of $G$ can be written in the form

$$A=e^{X_1}e^{X_2}\ldots{}e^{X_m}$$

for some $X_1$,$X_2$$\ldots$$X_m$ in the Lie algebra. Immeadiately after it is stressed that even if $G$ is connected, it is not true that any every element $A$ of $G$ canbe written

$$A=e^{X}$$

where $X$ is a Lie algebra element. My background is on physics, and I have many times seen Lie groups written using ony one exponential with absolute impunity (for example with $SU(2)$). Can anybody tell me when it is true that there is some $X$ Lie algebra element for every $A$ in a Lie group?

Comment: It's true for all compact groups (like $SU(2)$) and also $\mathbb{R}^n$ and products $G\times \mathbb{R}^n$ where $G$ is compact, but I don't know if it's true or not for anything else.  Maybe someone else can chime in?  (Later, I can supply a handwavy proof for compact groups.)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591689/the-condition-for-the-exponential-map-of-lie-group-is-surjective-or-injective), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups) and many other discussions on this subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $G$ is compact and connected, one can prove (by constructing a bi-invariant metric on $G$ and relating the metric and Lie group exponential maps) that the exponential map $\exp : {\frak g} \to G$ is surjective. This justifies the claim for, e.g., $SU(2)$. Using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, one can show that $\exp$ is also surjective for Lie groups that are connected, simply connected, and nilpotent. (See this [blog post of Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/two-small-facts-about-lie-groups/) for more.)

There is a condition on Lie groups *equivalent* to surjectivity of $\exp$, namely, divisibility: A group is **divisible** iff for every $g \in G$ and every $k \in \Bbb Z_+$ there is some $h \in G$ such that $h^k = g$. (See the paper cited below.) Checking this condition is not necessarily easier than checking surjectivity directly, however.

We can use this criterion to show readily that $\exp$ is not surjective for all connected Lie groups: For example, we can check directly that $B := \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-2}$ has no square root in $GL(2, \Bbb R)$ (say, by writing out the components of $X^2 = B$ and deriving a contradiction). So, $GL_+(2, \Bbb R) := \{A \in GL(2, \Bbb R) : \det A > 0\}$ is not divisible, and hence $\exp: {\frak gl}(2, \Bbb R) \to GL_+(2, \Bbb R)$ is not surjective.

> Hoffman, Lawson. *Divisible Semisubgroups of Lie Groups*. J. London Math. Soc. (1983) s2-27 (3): 427-434.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you justify the case of the identity component of the Lorentz group?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know offhand whether it *is* true for $SO_0(1, 3)$. I suspect it's false, and that one might be able to find a counterexample using that $SO_0(1, 2)$ has the same universal cover as $SL(2, \Bbb R)$, for which we've seen that $\exp$ is not surjective.

Comment: Apparently it is surjective. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Surjectiveness_of_exponential_mapping

Comment: @BrianKlatt Thanks for pointing this out---for anyone who doesn't bother to click through, one can show this using that (1) $SO_0(1, 3) \cong PGL(2, \Bbb C)$ and (2) $\exp: {\frak gl}(2, \Bbb C) \to GL(2, \Bbb C)$ *is* surjective. (I'd forgotten about the exceptional isomorphism in (1).)