# Exponential map from o(n) to O(n)

Tags: orthogonal-matrices, matrix-exponential, skew-symmetric-matrices

$o(n) =$ Set of all real skew-symmetric matrices
$O(n) =$ Set of all real orthogonal matrices

We know that whenever $X\in o(n)$ , then $e^X\in O(n)$. Also, I know that the map $g:o(n)\to O(n)$ such that $g(X)=e^X$ is a continuous map.

However, I'm unable to figure out whether this map is **surjective** or not, i.e. for every $Y\in O(n)$ , does $\exists$ some $X\in o(n)$ such that $Y=e^X$ ? Also, is this map necessarily **injective** ?

---

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this question is silly or previously answered.

Comment: Isn't the image the set of orthogonal matrices of determinant $+1$? See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130178/is-the-exponential-map-ever-not-injective